# DAX Power BI: Respect the individual format of each measure during concatenation

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have 2 measures that I want to concatenate while respecting their original format.
The last column should be `% ticket type (numberDistinctCount)`.

For example `59.83% (168,479)` but instead when I combine them both, it appears that the formatting was lost and becomes `0.598337950138504 (168479)`

The definition I use for the last column is

`% count ticket type = [% ticket type] & " (" & [numberDistinctCount] & ")"`

[image]

Is there a way to ensure that the concatenation of 2 measures respect the individual measure format?

The result of this concatenation will be used as a tooltip

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wrap your measures in `FORMAT` functions for this, else Power BI just defaults to the numerical output from your measure - in this case a decimal that is "primed" for percentage formatting.

Try this:

```
% count ticket type = 
FORMAT ( [% ticket type] , "0.00%" ) & " (" & [numberDistinctCount] & ")"
```

Comment: Thanks for introducing `Format` function, I updated a bit your code to format the `numberDistinctCount` part `% count ticket type = FORMAT ( [% ticket type] , "0.00%" ) & " (" & FORMAT ( [numberDistinctCount] , "#,#" ) & ")"`